# angular ng-options required not working with slim template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I google it and  no luck,so I need some help.

This is a problem when using angularjs, the ng-required not working.I used BS3,slim template ,rails as backend. The input element working fine.

```
form ng-submit="load()"
  input ng-required="true"
  select ng-model="m" ng-options="m for m in ['am','pm']"  ng-required="true"
  button.btn type="submit" load
```

ng-required="m" and required="" also not working

Sorry for my bad english and poor problem :<

Answer (score 1):

You should use **required** instead of **ng-required** like this

```
form ng-submit="load()"
   input ng-required="true"
   select ng-model="m" ng-options="m for m in ['am','pm']"  required
   button.btn type="submit" load
```

Here is a working jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/vikasgoyalgzs/qQdu5/

You should use ng-required only when you want to get the value of required from a scope variable or function.

e.g

```
//In view
ng-required="myScopeVariable"

//In controller
$scope.myScopeVariable = true;
```

or

```
//in View
ng-required="myScopeFunction()"

//in controller
$scope.myScopeFunction = function () {
   // your logic goes here
   return true;
};
```